# Prove $\langle u,v \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1}i^k \left \Vert u+i^kv \right \Vert$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

For an assignment in one of my math classes I have this problem. Here is where I have gotten so far. This is in V, an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$

$$\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1}i^k \left \Vert u+i^kv \right \Vert = \frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k \langle u+i^kv, u+i^kv \rangle\\
            = \frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k \langle u, u+i^kv \rangle + i^k \langle i^kv, u+i^kv\rangle \\
 =\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k\langle u,u+i^kv \rangle + i^{2k} \langle v, u+i^kv\rangle\\
=\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k \overline{\langle u+i^kv, u \rangle} + i^{2k} \overline{\langle u+i^kv, v\rangle}\\
 =\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k \overline{\langle u, u \rangle}+i^k \overline{\langle i^kv, u \rangle} + i^{2k} \overline{\langle u,v\rangle}+i^{2k} \overline{\langle i^kv,v\rangle}\\ 
 =\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k \overline{\langle u, u \rangle}+i^k\overline{i^k} \overline{\langle v, u \rangle} + i^{2k} \overline{\langle u,v\rangle}+i^{2k}\overline{i^k} \overline{\langle v,v\rangle}\\
=\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k \langle u, u \rangle-i^{2k} \langle u, v \rangle + i^{2k} \langle v,u\rangle-i^{3k} \langle v,v\rangle$$ 
After this, I try expanding the summation but it results in a very complicated series of sums and it does not reduce do $\langle u,v \rangle$. Any mistakes I did, or tips would be appreciated!

*EDIT* Found the solution! I should've stopped at step 3 $\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} i^k\langle u,u+i^kv \rangle + i^{2k} \langle v, u+i^kv\rangle$. Here you just do the sum for each value of k (k=1,2,3,4) and you will be able to eliminate every term and get $4\langle u,v \rangle$ .

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what to do after step 3? I've tried computing the sum in various ways but never got to 4⟨u,v⟩ Thanks

Comment: Compute the value of the inner product for k=1, k=2, k=3, k=4 separately. You will end up with  something$ \langle u,u \rangle + 1\langle u,v \rangle +$ something $\langle v,u \rangle + $ something $\langle v,v \rangle$. The $ \langle u,u \rangle, \langle v,u \rangle$ and $\langle v,v \rangle$ will cancel out and you will get $4 \langle u,v \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simpler approach uses $$\langle u+i^k v,\,u+i^k v\rangle=\langle u,\,u\rangle+(-1)^k\langle v,\,v\rangle+(i^{-k}\langle u,\,v\rangle+\text{c.c.})$$(note the plus-complex-conjugate grouping of cross terms). Your expression is then $$\frac{\sum_k \langle u,\,v\rangle+\sum_k i^k\langle u,\,u\rangle+\sum_k i^{2k}\langle v,\,u\rangle+\sum_k i^{3k}\langle v,\,v\rangle}{4}.$$Now use $\sum_k i^{jk}=4\delta_{j0}$ for $j\in\{0,\,\cdots,\,3\}$.

Comment: Shouldn't the $\langle u,u \rangle$ still be in the summation as the original equation is $\frac{1}{4} \sum^4_{k=1} \langle u+i^kv, u+i^kv \rangle$. Moreover, if I understand correctly there would only be an $\langle u,u \rangle$ left and we have to prove it equals $\langle u, v \rangle$

Comment: @TimBilodeau Sorry; see the edit.